# All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification but firebase doc gave me different version

Tags: android, firebase

My Android Studio giving me an error see below images

[image]

[image]

but firebase doc gave me a different version of many libraries, [here is the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

[image]

So my question is if firebase doc gives me this different version of libraries then why is android studio giving me this error?

Comment: Update your android studio, gradle, compile sdk version, google plugin version, etc.

Comment: I face the same problem. so I found the solution for me just downgrade to `16.0.0`

Comment: @NabinBhandari i will try that

Comment: @skpanchal but the latest version of firebase-ads is 15.0.1

Comment: but it not giving any type of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per one of comment suggested, Upgrading an Android Studio and Gradle version Did solve my problem, Previously I was using Android Studio 3.0 and after upgrading to Android Studio 3.1.3 this error was gone.

Below are the changes that I have made.

> Updated Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.1.3
>
> Updated Gradle Version to 4.4

If this will not fix your problem then try to upgrade your Google plugin version to the latest one

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:latest.version'

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the version of the version of the google services gradle plugin to the latest in you top-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

This is the plugin that checks for proper versions. Only newer versions of this plugin understand the new versioning system of the libraries.

Comment: gives me this error : Error:Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following google service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and upgrade firebase invites:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
```